# SpringXD Job is still executing even after forceful Server shutdown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-xd

I'm trying to run a Job on SpringXD and the job has 7 steps, When I reach step 4 i'm shutting down the XD server. When I look into the Metadata of SpringXD I'm saving on OracleDB. I see that the Step 4 is in executing status and it will never change to failed. After restarting the server, I still see that the status of the Job is still executing and it never gets finished. If I launch the job it create a new job and the new one gets finished.

My config.xml for jdbc:

```
    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" 
                      enabled="false">
        <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

1. From [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql](http://org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql), I see that the sql queries are for creating a table. But when the tables are already existing, as i didn't drop them from my previous job. There was no error which said tables already exist. The new job got appended to previous existing table. HOW?
2. How can I force the job to fail when the XD server suddenly goes down?
3. How can I resume the same job that was stopped from the step where it stopped?

Thank you :)

Comment: How are you killing the container?  If it's a `kill -9` style, the job isn't going to shut down gracefully and doesn't have the opportunity to update the tables of it's state.

Comment: @MichaelMinella .. yes I'm killing it using kill -9. Is there any way we can restart the executing job after the spring XD server is up?

Comment: That's a manual process.  Without giving the process the ability to gracefully shutdown, it's really a human decision as to what to do.  Do we restart, do we not, at what point to we restart...all of those are very use case specific decisions.

Comment: @MichaelMinella .. I totally agree with you. But if there server is down for some reason, then the springXD container will also be down and once the container is up. we won't be able to restart the executing job?

Comment: Not automatically, no.  There is no functionality within Spring XD to relaunch a job if a container fails because of the previously mentioned issues.

Comment: Can we manually do it?

Comment: Of course!!!!!!

Comment: @MichaelMinella.. Thank you for being patient with me.. i'm totally new to Spring and figuring my way. I have manually created another job and marking the job status in the BATCH_JOB_EXECTION to FAILED from STARTED.. But when I'm trying to restart the job using jobOperator.restart() the FAILED job is not getting restarted. Getting an exception for NoSuchJobExecutionException..

Comment: @MichaelMinella.. i'm trying to restart a jobA that is deployed from SpringXD and if the XD fails (kill -9) then I should be able to restart job A by running another job B, After the container is up. I was able to restart the jobA after marking it as FAILED and by using the XD SHELL by the command "job execution restart --id 0" I was able to restart the job from the point it stopped. Can I send this shell command from the jobB after making the jobA FAILED on the database. facing problem implementing the idea.


Thank you for Helping.. Means a lot to me